# Excel: Multiple File Run, Save Each File name as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works for one file. It reads the name of the .xlsx file and saves the Application.GetOpenFilename as a variable. This is then used later in the code.

I want to be able to run this code on multiple files... example:

User selects files names "x","y", and "z"

```
Sub Test()
  Dim myvariable as variant, i As Integer
  myvariable = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True)

  On Error GoTo ERRORHANDLER
  For i = 1 To UBound(myvariable)
    '''code to do stuff to my variable'''
  Next i

  Exit Sub

ERRORHANDLER:
  MsgBox "No files were selected, action cancelled."

End Sub
```

This code should run each time, doing the stuff to "x", then "y", then "z" but I keep getting the `ERRORHANDLER` message.

Update: 
When I put MsgBox ("Hello") in the "code to do stuff" it does print it for as many files as I select. When I write MsgBox (myvariable) I get that error, so I assume it is because Excel doesnt know how to save each individual filename as the variable during each loop through the code. –

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Comment out the error handling - where exactly does it fail and what is the error?  You code attributes all types of error to "no files selected": that's not necessarily accurate.

Comment: Hi Tim, I commented it out, and get the "Run time error 13, Type Mismatch" (I also tried changing the i = 1 to i = 0 as someone commented below, but got the same run time error.

Comment: When I put MsgBox ("Hello") in the "code to do stuff" it does print it for as many files as I select. When I write MsgBox (myvariable) I get that error, so I assume it is because Excel doesnt know how to save each individual filename as the variable during each loop through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to print error description unless you know the exact error.
You can find out the error by putting following line under your error handler.

```
MsgBox Err.Description
```

I tried your code with multiple selection after putting the simple msgbox and it does seem to work for me.
Check if you are missing i to refer the array.

```
MsgBox (myvariable(i))
```

Comment: Hi Imran! Thank you for your comment! All I needed to do was add the (i) and it worked! Is that essentially telling it to create an array from the selected file names?

Comment: myvariable was already declared as variant so essentially you it was created you are just accessing its members by i.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

In the loop declaration should be:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(myvariable)
```

Comment: Hi adarti, I tried that but unfortunately still got the "Run time error 13, Type Mismatch"